# How to mock a class method that is called from another class with pytest_mock

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

In the below files I have
`InternalDogWebhookResource` which calls `VisitOrchestrator.fetch_visit`.  I am attempting to write a test for `InternalDogWebhookResource` but mock `VisitOrchestrator.fetch_visit` since it is a network call.

I have tried the mock paths:

- `api.dog.handlers.internal.VisitOrchestrator.fetch_visit`
- `api.dog.handlers.internal.InternalDogWebhookResource.VisitOrchestrator.fetch_visit`
- `api.dog.handlers.internal.InternalDogWebhookResource.fetch_visit`

and many others, but I am always getting `AssertionError: assert None`

I can confirm that the `client.post` in the test works because when i remove the mock asserts, i get a response back from the api which means `fetch_visit` is called.

How can I find the `mocker.patch` path?

`api/dog/handlers/internal.py`

```
from api.dog.helpers.visits import VisitOrchestrator

@api.route("/internal/dog/webhook")
class InternalDogWebhookResource():

    def post(self) -> JsonResponse:
        if event_type == EventType.CHANGE:
            VisitOrchestrator.fetch_visit(event['visitId'])

        return JsonResponse(status=204)
```

`api/dog/helpers/visits.py`

```
class VisitOrchestrator:
    @classmethod
    def fetch_visit(cls, visit_id: str) -> VisitModel:
        # do stuff

        return visit
```

`tests/v0/dog/handlers/test_webhook.py`

```
import pytest
from pytest_mock import MockerFixture

from api.dog.handlers.internal import InternalDogWebhookResource, EventType
from tests.v0.utils import url_for


def test_webhook_valid(client, config, mocker: MockerFixture):
    visit_id = '1231231'

    mock_object = mocker.patch(
        'api.dog.handlers.internal.VisitOrchestrator.fetch_visit',
        return_value=visit_id,
    )

    res = client.post(
        url_for(InternalDogWebhookResource),
        json={'blag': 'blargh'}
    )
    assert mock_object.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: HI, I wonder what `client` is you test? An instance of `InternalDogWebhookResource`? Also, could this post be of some help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38579854/11246056

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the right things - your second approach is generally the way to go with mocks (mocking `api.dog.handlers.internal.InternalDogWebhookResource.VisitOrchestrator.fetch_visit`)

I would try to do the minimal test code function:

```
def test_webhook_valid(mocker):
    mock_fetch_visit = mocker.MagicMock(name='fetch_visit')
    mocker.patch('api.dog.handlers.internal.VisitOrchestrator.fetch_visit',
                 new=mock_fetch_visit)

    InternalDogWebhookResource().post()

    assert 1 == mock_fetch_visit.call_count
```

If this works for you - maybe the problem is with the `client` or other settings in your test method.

Comment: this worked! thanks. really curious as to why this worked with MagicMock, but not the other ways I was trying.