# How do I patch a python @classmethod to call my side_effect method?

Tags: python, mocking, patch

The following code shows the problem.

I can successfully patch object instance and static methods of this `SomeClass`

However, I can't seem to be able to patch classmethods.

Help much appreciated!

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
from unittest.mock import patch


class SomeClass:
    def instance_method(self):
        print("instance_method")

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        print("static_method")

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        print("class_method")

# --- desired patch side effect methods ----
def instance_method(self):
    print("mocked instance_method")

def static_method():
    print("mocked static_method")

def class_method(cls):
    print("mocked class_method")

# --- Test ---
obj = SomeClass()

with ExitStack() as stack:
    stack.enter_context(
        patch.object(
            SomeClass,
            "instance_method",
            side_effect=instance_method,
            autospec=True
        )
    )
    stack.enter_context(
        patch.object(
            SomeClass,
            "static_method",
            side_effect=static_method,
            # autospec=True,
        )
    )
    stack.enter_context(
        patch.object(
            SomeClass,
            "class_method",
            side_effect=class_method,
            # autospec=True
        )
    )


    # These work
    obj.instance_method()
    obj.static_method()

    # This fails with TypeError: class_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'
    obj.class_method()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38579854/13891412 ?

Comment: Nice at @Clasherkasten. If I replace `side_effect=` with `new=` for the class_method case, it seems to work. Not sure I understand it though. When would one use `side_effect=` and when `new=` in general?

Comment: I don't have any clue about that either, sorry. I just found that answer, tested it and suggested it cause it seemed to work.

Comment: Ah ok, fair enough. However, although it works now when calling from the `obj` handle, it doesn't seem to work when attempting to call the @classmethod from its class handle. i.e. calling `SomeClass.class_method()`  inside the `with` block still fails with `TypeError: class_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls'`

Comment: `new=classmethod(class_method)` seems to make it work again :)

Comment: Once again, niiice! That seems to successfully patch both `obj.class_method()` and `SomeClass.class_method()`. It only works with `new` and not `side_effect`. Would be great to know the difference between those two. In the meantime, if you want to answer I'll upvote you and check as the correct answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250635/discussion-between-oldschool-and-clasherkasten).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General solution

A way to patch a classmethod would be to use `new=classmethod(class_method)` instead of `side_effects=class_method`.
This works pretty well in general.

### Downside

Using `new`, the patched object isn't necessarily an instance of `Mock`, `MagicMock`, `AsyncMock` or `PropertyMock` anymore (During the rest of the answer i'll only reference `Mock` as all the others are subclasses of it). 
It is only then an instance of these when you explicitly specify it to be one via e.g. `new=Mock(...)` or ommit the attribute completely. 
That wouldn't be the case with the solution provided at the top of this answer.
So when you try to e.g. check if the function already got called using `obj.class_method.assert_called()`, it'll give an error saying that `function has no attribute assert_called` which is caused by the fact that the patched object isn't an instance of `Mock`, but instead a `function`.

**Unfortunately I don't see any solution to this downside in that scenario at the moment**

### Concluded differences between `new` and `side_effect`:

- `new` specifies what object to patch the target with (doesn't necessarily have to be an instance of `Mock`)
- `side_effect` specifies the side_effect of the `Mock` instance that gets created when using patch without `new`
  Also they don't play very well together, so only one of these can/should be used in the same `patch(...)`.

Comment: Thank you for putting this answer together @Clasherkasten. I'm not very good with this bit of the language. It would be great to find out whether or not there is a way to patch class methods whilst retaining the Mock properties of the created object/class. I am nevertheless up voting your answer and marking it as correct because it does solve the problem I had as stated in the question. Thank you!